# How to inject external js files to an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to insert jQuery and another JS file in an iframe. I was wondering whether it's possible, or are there some issues about that?

Let us say those pages are just running on the same domain name.

The parent page will try to override the elements inside an iframe using Javascript.
Then I need to add another jQuery library on the subpage (http://jsbin.com/esifez/2).

Any idea about this?

```
$(function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
  $("#main_iframe").contents().find("body").append(script);
});
```

[Demo link](http://jsbin.com/ilabad/2).

Thank you

Comment: are you aware of the same origin policy? will parent and subpage be served from the same domain in your end solution?

Comment: yes stated above :) it will be running on the same origin.

Answer (score 1):

In your demo link your iframe already contains javascript trying to access `$` or `jQuery` way before your `find("body").append(script);` will ever get computed. So this will fire an error because `$` doesn't exist yet. You either need to do one of two things:

1. Include the jQuery script tag in the head of your iframe's source manually. Considering you have jQuery code in your iframe source, why not do this anyway?
2. Don't have any script trying to access `jQuery` or `$` in your iframe's source, unless the references are within functions or separate scripts that will only ever be executed after you have inserted your jQuery script tag.

Basically for point number 2, don't have this directly in your iframe:

```
<script>
  /// dolar wont exist yet
  $(function(){

  })
</script>
```

Instead do this in your parent code:

```
var insertScript = function(src){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = src;
  $("#main_iframe").contents().find("body").append(script);
}

$(function() {
  insertScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
  // any code in your iframe that relies on jQuery should be 
  // moved off into this file
  insertScript('iframe-js-code-that-requires-jq.js');
});
```

However it still makes more sense to have the jQuery script tag already within your iframe source, and not to dynamically insert it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a permission to write on the file so I'm just overriding using iframe. But the file i'm overriding and the page containing it is only the same domain name.

Comment: I tried the second approach because It's more suited to what I need. But for some reason it's loading the script on the parent page rather than the sub page inside the iframe. Demo here: (http://jsbin.com/ilabad/3/), any idea? thanks!

Comment: @Pennf0lio it's just a guess but you may need to use the iframe's document object to create the script elements - rather than the parent's one, however... *(continued in next comment)*.

Comment: @Pennf0lio I'm afraid unless you can remove the jQuery references from the iframe file your js wont get very far into it's execution for that page. The inline script tags will execute as soon as they are read and there is no easy/safe way of stepping in before the iframe renders it's HTML. If you don't have permissions to edit the file, one thing you could do instead is to read the iframe file through a proxy script powered by some back-end code like php or phython. This backend script would read your iframe source and either strip or add elements that you need.. like a jQuery script tag.